# Is there an injective continuous map $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

It is commonly known fact that there exists a continuous surjective map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. So it bids to ask:

Is there an injective continuous map $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Such a map would restrict to a homemorphism from the unit ball around $0$ to a closed interval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  If so by connectivity the image would be an interval.  Removing any $3$ points in the image will disconnect it, however, removing the corresponding $3$ points in the domain will not disconnect $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then we have a continuous map from a connected set onto a disconnected set.

This also shows there isn't a continuous finite to $1$ map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Actually it shows there isn't a continuous countable to $1$ map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a countable set removed is path connected.